# how to copy a particular column values from one dataframe to another dataframe based on matching entry in pandas

Tags: pandas

```
Dataframe1:
   invoice match_code
0    1        5
1    2        6
2    3        7
3    4        8
```

```
Dataframe2:
   invoice
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

I want to update the dataframe2 based on matching values in the invoice column

```
   invoice match_code
0    1        5
1    2        6
2    3        7
```

I am new to pandas and I tried apply function, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `df2.merge(df1,on='invoice')` or `df2['invoice'].map(df1.set_index('invoice')['match_code'])`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried using the second method, but I am getting this error "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects" because I am having additional columns in both dataframe @AnuragDabas

Comment: Actually in my case, the first dataframe is the result of merging two dataframes and second dataframe is one of the dataframe used for merging @AnuragDabas

Comment: then merge with the subset of df1 `df2.merge(df1[['invoice','match_code']],on='invoice')`....and for 2nd method I think invoice is already an index in your actual dataframe